# jQuery count height of elements with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can't figure out this trivial thing. Have several elements with different classes and I need to count `height` of that one which has for example class `.a`.

```
<div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

I would need to get the result count in variable `count_of_a` so something like that:

```
var count_of_a = jQuery( ".a" ).each(function(){
    jQuery(this).height();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're close :)

the definition of `each` is

> Function( Integer index, Element element )

so you need the second argument to access your current object

try this :

```
var totalHeight = 0;

jQuery('.a').each(function(index ,element ){

    totalHeight +=  jQuery(element).height();

});

console.log(totalHeight);
```

here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uduauxrg/8/

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```
$('.a').height() * $('.a').length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('div.a').each(function(){
        alert($(this).height());
    });
});
```

Do you mean you want the height value total or respectively?
Here's an example shows individual height of class a div.